# Using %in% for multiple criteria simultaneously

Tags: r

I have a dataframe showing some data on individuals (`ID`), where for each year they live there is one row. It also contains information on parent ID (`P.ID`) and parent age when born (`P.AB`).

```
# Dataframe A: 1 row per individual
dfA <- data.frame(
  "ID"   = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
  "P.ID" = c(NA,  "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
  "P.AB" = c(NA, 3, 4, 2, 4),
  "LS" = c(5, 6, 3, 4, 5))

# Dataframe B: 1 row per year of life
dfB <- data.frame("ID" = rep(dfA[,'ID'], dfA[,'LS']+1))
dfB <- merge(dfB, dfA, by = "ID")

dfB[ ,'AGE'] <- 0
for(i in 2:length(dfB[,1])){
  if(dfB[i,'ID'] == dfB[i-1, 'ID']){
    dfB[i,'AGE'] <- dfB[i-1, 'AGE'] + 1
  }
}
```

Giving:

```
> head(dfB)
  ID P.ID P.AB LS AGE
1  A <NA>   NA  5   0
2  A <NA>   NA  5   1
3  A <NA>   NA  5   2
4  A <NA>   NA  5   3
5  A <NA>   NA  5   4
6  A <NA>   NA  5   5
```

What I am trying to do is then get R to put a "1" into column `REP` to show the years in which an individual reproduced. E.g. *B* was born to *A* when *A* was 3, so the row where *A* is 3 years old gets a 1. I have been trying to do this using `%in%` but struggling to make this work with multiple criteria. A work around is to paste together the `ID` and `age` (plus a random string to make sure that there is no false duplication in my larger dataset), but this feels like it is lacking elegance and is unnecessarily complex. I wonder **can/how does one use `%in%` for multiple criteria**?

```
# Add 1 where an individual reproduced
dfB[,'REP'] <- 0
dfB[,'T1'] <- paste0(dfB[,'AGE'],  "abcdefghijk656hjhjhj", dfB[,'ID'])
dfB[,'T2'] <- paste0(dfB[,'P.AB'], "abcdefghijk656hjhjhj", dfB[,'P.ID'])
dfB[,'REP'][dfB[,'T1'] %in% dfB[,'T2']] <- 1
dfB[,'T2'] <- dfB[,'T1'] <- NULL
dfB
```

The output would then look like this:

```
> dfB
   ID P.ID P.AB LS AGE REP
1   A <NA>   NA  5   0   0
2   A <NA>   NA  5   1   0
3   A <NA>   NA  5   2   0
4   A <NA>   NA  5   3   1
5   A <NA>   NA  5   4   1
6   A <NA>   NA  5   5   0
7   B    A    3  6   0   0
8   B    A    3  6   1   0
9   B    A    3  6   2   1
10  B    A    3  6   3   0
11  B    A    3  6   4   1
12  B    A    3  6   5   0
13  B    A    3  6   6   0
14  C    A    4  3   0   0
15  C    A    4  3   1   0
16  C    A    4  3   2   0
17  C    A    4  3   3   0
18  D    B    2  4   0   0
19  D    B    2  4   1   0
20  D    B    2  4   2   0
21  D    B    2  4   3   0
22  D    B    2  4   4   0
23  E    B    4  5   0   0
24  E    B    4  5   1   0
25  E    B    4  5   2   0
26  E    B    4  5   3   0
27  E    B    4  5   4   0
28  E    B    4  5   5   0
```

---

I tried this (and some variants of) which gets close, correctly adding them to the right individuals, but at the wrong years - it's seeing that *A* and *B* both reproduce, and that reproductions occurred at ages 2, 3, and 4 (6 events in total), but not that *A* and *B* both reproduce at age 4, while *A* also reproduces at age 3, and *B* also reproduces at age 2 (4 events in total):

```
dfB[,'REP'][dfB[,'P.ID'] %in% dfB[,'ID'] & dfB[,'P.AB'] %in% dfB[,'AGE']] <- 1  
dfB[,'REP'][dfB[,'ID'] %in% dfB[,'P.ID'] & dfB[,'AGE'] %in% dfB[,'P.AB'] ] <- 1
```

---

As an extension on this, I'd like to have the number of offspring per age, rather than just a 1 or 0, this works (I change `dfA` so that *B* and *C* are twins), but is also probably inefficient:

```
# Counts of offspring per year
dfA[,'PASTED'] <- paste0(dfA[,'P.ID'], "randomtext",  dfA[,'P.AB'])
# Create rep column
dfB[,'REP'] <- 0
# Paste together ID and AGE columns to give unique row identifiers
dfB[,'T1'] <- paste0(dfB[,'AGE'],  "randomtext", dfB[,'ID'])
dfB[,'T2'] <- paste0(dfB[,'P.AB'], "randomtext", dfB[,'P.ID'])
# Add Reps
dfB[,'REP'][dfB[,'T1'] %in% dfB[,'T2']] <- table(dfA[,'PASTED'])
# Remove excess columns
dfB[,'T2'] <- dfB[,'T1'] <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about using `%in%` with more than one column, then you are probably looking for a merge/join. You can do this all with base R, but I find it a bit easier to do with some help from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dfB %>% 
  select(P.ID, P.AB) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(P.ID)) %>% 
  rename(ID=P.ID, AGE=P.AB) %>% 
  mutate(REP=1) %>% 
  left_join(dfB, .) %>% 
  mutate(REP=coalesce(REP, 0))
```

Basically you just find the unique parent/age values from the data, then you join that back to the same data.frame, but match on different columns.